# Is there a better alternative to AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I know that *AlarmManager* can set off alarms to trigger certain activity or service, but I've seen that the alarm gets cancelled once the app has been closed. What if I want the app to trigger the alarm even when my phone is in sleep mode or has closed the app? Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: check out WorkManager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: https://github.com/evernote/android-job

Comment: AlarmManager can work when app is closed but the phone is on.

Comment: "I've seen that the alarm gets cancelled once the app has been closed" -- no, it does not, at least on normal devices. There is the occasional dim-witted device manufacturer who does something like have a proprietary task manager do a "force stop" (to use the Settings app's button's name). "Force stop" will remove scheduled alarms. Ordinary process termination -- whether via a task manager or just the passage of time -- does not remove scheduled alarms.

Comment: @amitava, it also works when you minimize the app, but nor after you close it (here closing means removing the app from recent apps).

Comment: as CommonsWare said: you will receive alarm notifications even if you "close" your app

Comment: @pskink by closing do you mean minimizing the app or removing it from the recent apps?

Comment: by closing i mean even physical process termination

Comment: and the only way your alarms are canceled is when a device shuts down (reboots), more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#boot), anyway you can read more about scheduling alarms [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

Comment: @Abhishek What device are you testing on?

Comment: @Srikar Reddy Asus Zenfone Max ZC550KL